# Suggestion: Making a "Hall Of Fame" section

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I suggest that we do a hall of fame section on SE, it's different from 'top users" section.

**This is how it works:**

- Every year, moderators from all over SE network vote for a user or more *(you decide)* to enter the hall of fame *(beta sites moderators doesn't count because the site could close down at any moment)*
- The hall of fame inductee reputation doesn't matter, as long as he deserve it, moderators decide if deserve it or not
- Unless the user gets banned, he's a hall of famer for ever
- And of course, a moderator cannot vote for himself

**Being a hall of famer will give you the following privileges**

- Entering the hall of fame section
- Getting the hall of fame badge and hall of fame star next to your name on all SE sites (maybe not a star, you decide)
- Making you a permanent moderator on the site you use the most
- SE representatives will get to meet you or do a Google hangout with you and you'll be featured on the SE blog
- You'll be given a gift, you're name on it and a thank you note *(or something, you decide)*

You can add add to that list or edit it, the way you want, I just suggested stuff. Improvements can be made.

---

**Why I suggested that?**

Because I believe that some users, those who dedicated so much time of their **real** lives to the SE network, deserve more than reputation. They deserve real gifts (material gifts), a thank you note and something that would show them how much they mean to the SE community.

Comment: *"Making you a permanent moderator on the site you use the most"* ... no .. just no.

Comment: @Bart This list could be improved, I am giving ideas, you get to add or edit or remove!

Comment: I'm not sure how feasible this is but I think it's an interesting idea. I'm not sure I can agree that we "deserve" more because I truly believe I learn *at least* as much by helping others but I get your point. You would need certain criteria so the mods didn't just pick the top user every year (maybe something about how they treat new/other members) but it might be too much for the mods to keep track of. They are busy little folks as it is.

Comment: @codeMagic moderators would create this criteria, I cannot create the criteria, I'm just giving you something to think about

Comment: If you're here because you want a gift, you're here for the wrong reason.  Aside from that, I DETEST Halls of Fame because they're nothing but popularity contests.  They become exclusionary.  They are unnecessary.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I've never said that, all im saying is that a thank you gift would be nice

Comment: @Fischer - You actually specifically said you "deserve real gifts (material gifts)".  So, yes, you did say that.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I did say exactly say that, but I didn't say, **I am here because I want a gift**, Einstein didn't do what he did because he wanted a nobel prize either.

Comment: As a moderator, I absolutely do not want this kind of responsibility. I prefer my focus being on content, and not people. Except, well, when they are being naughty - but that's not a part of the "job" I particularly enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

See, the current system rewards and gives credit to the "MVP's" of StackOverflow - via badges and extra responsibilities.

But you have to be here because you *enjoy* helping. we don't want people who answer and comment with a hidden-notion that they'll get a material reward.

One glaring issue with this is the line:

> Making you a permanent moderator on the site you use the most

Permanent? That word is scary

Comment: Ya.  Plus, what if I use Facebook more?  Then it's lies.  All lies...

Comment: hehe, good stufff